# Add a master page programmatically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

First off, I know this isn't a normal thing to do, so if it isn't possible, just let me know.

I have a bunch of pages (100+) that are all designed to be contained within an iframe.  Recently, I've decided to move away from this and use a master page to do some formatting on the page that used to contain the iframe.  However, in order to do this, the page inside the frame is now going to be the page that is navigated to.  What I need to be able to do is apply this new master page to a page that didn't have a master page prior and I'd like to do it without having to change the markup of all the other pages.  All of these pages inherit from a single parent class that can be used to accomplish this, if it is possible.  It is necessary that iframes are not used in this solution, as their compatibility is part of the problem I'm trying to work around.  Thanks for any help/ideas you can offer.

**EDIT**

This is the error I'm getting when I try the way the comments suggest:

> Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.

Answer (score 2):

Should be very possible. As I recall, you can just have your base class set its own MasterPage in the OnPreInit event:

```
this.MasterPage = "~/SpecificMasterPage.aspx";
```

#### Response to comments

That complicates things. Here's something you can try, but I don't know whether it will work: try creating regular page to be your "master" page, and loading the other pages in as if they were controls using the `Page.LoadControl` method. I don't know whether whole pages can be loaded this way, and even if they are this is hacky at best, since you'll be producing new `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags within the body of the page.

So your best bet is probably to convert all your pages to either use a MasterPage or to be Controls. If you're clever, you might be able to write a little program that can do this to all your pages automatically.

Comment: yep, that will do it. I do this a lot in multi-company CMS system where the masterpage is set depending on the company.

Comment: The problem is that the page does not have a master page to begin with.  Thus it contains things like <html> and <form> tags and not <asp:Content> tags.

Comment: It needs to happen in the `OnPreInit` event.

Comment: Yep, I got that too.  I'll post the error I receive when trying that in my question.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid: Thanks. I fixed the instructions.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Any other ideas?